# Python GeoPandas: fill small gaps between Linestrings in a graph to get only one connected component?

Tags: python, geopandas, graph

I have a graph in Python GeoPandas with many connected components. And I want to create a graph with only one connected component.

Does there exist some convenience functions to fill the gaps in GeoPandas?

Comment: Sorry, but unless you add a code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: And a screenshot would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation which requires `pygeos`, but it is fast. Notice that it does not preserve any attributes as it works on numpy array of pygeos geometries.

See details on pygeos backed in geopandas - https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency

```py
def close_gaps(df, tolerance):
    """Close gaps in LineString geometry where it should be contiguous.
    Snaps both lines to a centroid of a gap in between.
    """
    geom = df.geometry.values.data
    coords = pygeos.get_coordinates(geom)
    indices = pygeos.get_num_coordinates(geom)

    # generate a list of start and end coordinates and create point geometries
    edges = [0]
    i = 0
    for ind in indices:
        ix = i + ind
        edges.append(ix - 1)
        edges.append(ix)
        i = ix
    edges = edges[:-1]
    points = pygeos.points(np.unique(coords[edges], axis=0))

    buffered = pygeos.buffer(points, tolerance)

    dissolved = pygeos.union_all(buffered)

    exploded = [
        pygeos.get_geometry(dissolved, i)
        for i in range(pygeos.get_num_geometries(dissolved))
    ]

    centroids = pygeos.centroid(exploded)

    snapped = pygeos.snap(geom, pygeos.union_all(centroids), tolerance)

    return snapped
```

Source of the function: https://github.com/urbangrammarai/spatial_signatures/blob/4c71c16940ebe695b3765a98041d326e73113a46/spatial_unit/snap.py#L209

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have small gaps in your line (or disconnected lines).  You need to find those lines, use geopandas to find the nearest geometries within a buffer, then use shapely.ops nearest_point.  Then gap the bridge between both geometries.